# What do those double dots mean (in Trois mouvements de Petrouchka, Stravinsky)

Tags: piano, notation

What do those double dots mean ?

Do they apply to the whole chord ? Or just the right hand chord or just the top D ? Does it have a musical meaning or interpretative meaning or both ? How is it different from *staccato* ?

in *Semaine grasse* (5th page of the movement, 2nd line or bars 57,58), *Trois mouvements de Petrouchka*, Stravinsky:

[image: line with double dots]

To my knowledge there is only one edition (I do not count localisation as an edition).

In the original, those bars correspond to the **95** or bars 3,4 in the following extract:

[image: original score]

The transcription (which is not a transcription, as stated by Stravinsky), has changed the text slightly.

Comment: Oh great, now I'm wondering whether those dots merely emphasize that those are 16th notes in the tremolo, the dots mean that those are all played staccato, or I am supposed to play 2 of each chord in the tremolo in a row (so the tremolo goes A-A-G-G instead of A-G-A-G).

Comment: @Aaron The original and 3 movements do not match since there are many cuts, simplifications, and addendi. It's mm 57,58

Comment: Closely related [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/94311/2600) if not even duplicate.

Comment: @guidot - I'd say that's only a closely related question since such dots for a single tremolo beam are a *lot* less confusing than those for a double tremolo.

Comment: @guidot dup for only one part of my questions, the case is more complicated here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is a not very good shorthand for

[image]

Comment: This works as a transcription of the flute and clarinet parts (remembering to transpose the clarinet). Note that I am not the Peter who answered the question.

Answer (score 4):

The notation is very ambiguous, but it's most likely that something like this is intended:

[image]

This preserves the legato tremolo of the original.

Comment: Do you mean the staccato is only for the D ?

Comment: @Soleil Yes. I think that's the most likely interpretation, and it makes the most musical sense.

Comment: This is probably the best answer given the notation and the orchestral context, but is hell to play.

Comment: @Peter Stravinsky gives a tempo of half-note=69. It's hard enough to play those repeated notes at all, let alone make them staccato.

Comment: @PiedPiper I'd not looked for the metronome mark in the orchestral score (I don't have a copy of the piano version - is it the same?). I take your point.

Answer (score 3):

The double dots indicate that each chord should be played twice within the tremolo (see below). Stravinsky is attempting to incorporate both the smooth tremolos in the woodwinds with the pizzicato in the violins. Note that the violins play each pitch (chord) twice before changing.

```
X: 1
T: Petrouchka tremolos
K: F
M: 6/4
L: 1/16
([Acfa]d[Acfa]d) .[Acd].[Acd].[GBd].[GBd] ([Acfa]d[Acfa]d) .[Acd].[Acd].[GBd].[GBd] ([Acfa]d[Acfa]d) .[Acd].[Acd].[GBd].[GBd] |
```

Comment: But we have that also without the double dot, isn't it a staccato for each "play" of the chord ?

Comment: @Aaron We seem to have almost coincided with the same answer!

Comment: @Soleil Without the dots, you wouldn't play it so staccato. As a rule of thumb, without the dots each note is about 3/4 the length of the notated value, with the dots it's about 1/2. Adjust to fit the tempo of the piece, the acoustic of the hall, the responsiveness of the piano and the flexibility of your wrist.

Comment: @Peter Yeah, at first I thought we were exactly the same, but then I saw we differ on whether or not to repeat each chord. I think you hit the nail on the head with "not a very good shorthand."

Comment: @Soleil The double dot indicates the repetition of the chord as well as staccato.

Comment: If this is what's intended, then the tremolo marking would be unnecessary.

Comment: @PiedPiper I think the tremolo is just there for consistency of notation across the passage as well as to clarify the relationship to the original score.

Comment: Peter's answer comes closer to the original and preserves the tremolo.

Comment: I don't think it's correct, it would not match the tremolo writing AND the left hand AND the original score.

Comment: @PiedPiper Look at the pizzicato violin in the original score. They repeat each chord. Otherwise there's no need for the double dot.

Comment: @Soleil It corresponds to the violin part in the original score, but as sixteenths instead of eighths to preserver the overall rhythm.

Comment: @Aaron Your proposal does not respect the harmony, the tremolo does as well as the rythm.

Comment: @PiedPiper The violins play eighths, pizzicato. Stravinsky is trying to have it both ways: preserving some of the pizzicato contrast with the smoother tremolos but in a way that makes rhythmic sense.

Comment: @PiedPiper You are 2 bars too much forward, there is no trumpet at sign 95. Aaron is doubling the speed of the violins for some reason. The tremolos are from the clarinets.

Comment: @Soleil How does it not respect the harmony? The harmony is the same either way.

Comment: @Soleil The speed is doubled because the overall feel of the passage is sixteenths. To suddenly switch to eighths would be jarring and would lose the overall feel. It's a compromise between wanting to contrast the smooth and pizz. tremolos while maintaining an overall rhythmic consistency.

Comment: @Aaron Check the harmony of clarinets.

Comment: @Soleil Don't forget this is an arrangement. The trumpet part is the only part playing those staccato sixteenths, and it looks like the arrangement  refers to that a couple of bars earlier.

Answer (score 1):

To add some "weight" to the answers that say this means each note is played twice, here's an example from a G&S score. You can see they explicitly wrote in the "slash" so you know there are two notes to be played per written flag.
I agree that the OP's example is already pretty crowded, so sticking in the slashes is pretty much redundant with the tremolo markings.

[image]